# Can I install DirectX 9 without it affecting the latest version?

Tags: windows, directx-9, retroarch

I'm attempting to run RetroArch for an old game, but it requires DirectX 9.0c.

Will installing DirectX 9.0c overwrite or delete the current version I have installed (v12)? If so, can I subsequently remove DirectX 9.0c if I have to run newer games?

Comment: If you have Windows 10, I'd expect DX9 to be already installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Game asking to install older directx. Should I allow it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/155881/game-asking-to-install-older-directx-should-i-allow-it)

Comment: @pppery I’m not sure whether this is a duplicate of [that question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/155881/4797) because installing DX9.0c is different from installing DX6 on a modern OS. (It’s not necessary to install DX6 in a modern OS.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Installing DirectX 9 won't affect games that require DirectX 10 or newer, so you can install it without any worries and won't need to uninstall it either.

The different versions will coexist side by side, through completely separate DLLs.